# How to use voice and speech recognition in C#?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

what do i need to install?

How to use/implement it?

Please give me example in using it.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

1. Google c# voice recognition
2. Investigate which of the suggestions you like best
3. Try the examples, and modify it to your needs.
4. If you have problems, come back to stack overflow and show us what you've done and what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Speech.Recognition library from Visual Studio. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh361683(v=office.14).aspx) an easy example.